# body and html not scaling outside of viewport when Zooming in Safari / Chrome

Tags: css, zooming, viewport

We've coded a site, everything works great until you start using the zoom function of Safari/Chrome.

It seems some elements zoom correctly (see the search in attached screenshot) making a horizontal scrollbar, but html and head don't scale more than 100% of the viewport so when you scroll right making it look pretty bad…

I've tried width: 100% !important and many other things but nothing seems to affect it, any ideas would be most appreciated!

[image: Example in Chrome, showing how html doesn't scale]

Comment: Turns out this isn't actually only when you zoom, if you resize your browser below the width of the container (980px) and then scroll horizontally you get the same effect. hmmmm!

Comment: And we can see this for ourselves...how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix seems to be putting a min-width on the body that's the same as the containers width, not ideal but seems to do the trick…!